# jQuery error - SyntaxError: missing : after property id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting an error "SyntaxError: missing : after property id" in the following code.

```
jQuery("#username_update").validate({

        rules : {
            new-username : {
                required : true,
                email : true
            },
            retype-username : {
                required : true,
                email : true
            }
        },

        messages : {
            new-username : {
                required : "New User Name must be filled in"
            },
            retype-username : {
                required : "Retype User Name must be filled in"
            }
        }

    });
```

Error is occurring at rules : { new-username : { line. Any help?

Comment: invalid json using "-"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use

```
"new-username" : {
                required : "New User Name must be filled in"
            }
```

instead of

```
new-username : {
                required : "New User Name must be filled in"
            }
```

Answer (score 6):

new-username is not valid property name. Quote it, or use underscore.
Unqoted property name have to obey javascript identifier rules (alphanumeric plus underscore and dollar). Quoted property may be any string.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use "-" in the property name new-username. Use underscore...